# 'A moduleName is required to create an RCTRootView'

Tags: react-native

This is the error shown:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'A moduleName is required to create an RCTRootView' in Xcode.

If needed I'll send anything, I don't really know what to send. Can someone help?

I tried to run my app in Xcode using React Native CLI, and that error message appeared after a successful build. It was working fine before, now I don't know.